# Return hierarchy from sql in lists in c# using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, hierarchy

I have table in sql which have three columns (ID, Name, ParentID) and each columns have many records. Now what i want is to get all hiearachy from ParrentId, to include it in three view.

Is that can be solved with some nice LINQ solution?

What i try before is to use set of List-s which one of those is child, but problem occur cause some child list can also have more childs under.

I need this with linq code:

```
    List<Menu> hList = new List<Menu>();

var m1 = new Menu();

var m2 = new Menu();
var m3 = new Menu();

hList.AddRange(new List<Menu>() { m1, m2, m3});
```

but of course in real example it wouldnt be just 3 child var-s.

Thnx  for any help and suggestion!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968069/linq-sort-a-flat-list-based-on-childorder

Comment: +1 Just a wild dice throw, but could something like this not be achieved with `AssociateWith`? Are you looking for a linq equivalent for T-Sql's `WITH` in combination with `UNION`?

Comment: Are you mapping this data from your database with linq-to-sql or linq-to-entities? If so, can you not just modify your table so that you have a self-referencing foreign key reference ParentID->ID...that will automatically map your object in the required hierarchy when you retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void FillMenu(EntityCollection menuList, List<Menu> hList, int? parentMenuId)
    {
        var g = from m in menuList
                where ((MenuEntity)m).ParentMenuId == parentMenuId
                select (MenuEntity)m;

        foreach (MenuEntity menu in g)
        {
            var newMenu = new Menu();
            newMenu.Id = menu.Id;
            newMenu.Name = menu.Name;

            newMenu.ChildMenu = new List<Menu>();

            FillMenu(menuList, newMenu.ChildMenu, newMenu.Id);

            hList.Add(newMenu);
        }

    }
```