# IComparer logic sort of hierachy structure to a flat list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, icomparer

I am currently developing a IComparer and its working fine for simple properties that are int and string, also the asending and descending is working, but I am facing a problem with a datastructure thats hierarchical.

Lets assume you have the following table in your database:

```
HierarchyTable
    ID, int
    Name, string
    SortOrder, int
    ParentID, int
```

The HierarchyTable is has a relation between ID and ParentID to build up a self referencing relation, that builds our hierarchy.

Now the problem starts with my SortOrder. The SortOrder isnt a unique int that is representing the sortorder for the whole level, instead it only stores the sortorder of the current level you are in.

Lets assume the following data:

```
ID --- Name --- SortOrder --- ParentID
1  --- A    --- 0         --- null
2  --- B    --- 1         --- 4
3  --- C    --- 2         --- 1
4  --- D    --- 1         --- 1
5  --- E    --- 1         --- 3
```

This would result in the following hierarchy:

```
ID --- Name --- SortOrder --- ParentID
1  --- A    --- 0         --- null
    4  --- D    --- 1         --- 1
        2  --- B    --- 1         --- 4
    3  --- C    --- 2         --- 1
        5  --- E    --- 1         --- 3
```

Now I wish to have this hierarchy in a flat list, with the help of an IComparer and a List that just calls the Sort method and voila here is a correct sorted flat list.

This table structure is in my **Entity Framework** application and represenst **one of entities**, so if I need to I could extend this with other properties.

The Entity for this simple example would look something like this:

```
public class HierarchyTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public in ParentID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties created by Entity Framework
    public virtual HierarchyTable Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HierarchyTable> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've accomplished something similar to this in the past by using a [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). Not sure this solves your immediate problem but may point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Rand Random - is the hierarchical tree structure already built or do you just need the tree flattened?

Comment: @drankin2112 Not sure what you mean, I try to explain it, maybe it solves your question. The EF builds the hierachical tree itself, with the Parent, Children properties of the class, so I could fetch either all HierachyTable Entities with "context.HierachyTables.Local" (Local is inbuild in EF and gets an entire list of them all), or I could add a where condition like ".Where(x => x.Parent == null)" which would result in only the root elements, and then I could navigate threw the Children Properties, but my problem isnt flatting the HierachyTable per se but doing this with the IComparer.

Comment: In your example hierarchy, are IDs 3 and 5 wrong because their sort order is backwards? If so, are you wanting to traverse the tree and have each level sorted using an IComparer? Or, are you saying that after the hierarchy has already been flattened, you want to sort that list using an IComparer? Sorry for the questions, I'm just trying to get clear.

Comment: @drankin2112 I dont see an error in my example, ID 3 is the second child of the ID 1 so it has the SortOrder 2, ID 5 is the first child of ID 3 so it has SortOrder 1. I dont see why you mean they are backwards. Maybe you can explain the error to me? In the endresult I want to have 1 IComparer that results in a flat list of all elements, and in additional I want to changed the NavigationProperty from ICollection<HierachyTable> to a list that has the IComparer specified, so that the childrens are also sorted correctly. No need to say sorry for questions, I am the one who needs help. :)

Comment: Don't be sorry, I guess I just don't understand the question. I wasn't saying that they are backwards, I was asking. :) I updated my answer with an IComparer implementation but I'm obviously not quite understanding the problem. If EF generates the hierarchy sorted correctly, and flattening it is no big deal, where is the problem? Maybe explaining where my first answer falls short would help me to understand what you mean. I really am just trying to help.

Comment: EF doesnt generate the hierachy sorted correct.Your update isnt what I am looking for because you are comparing the ID with the ParentID which may fit in my simple example, but not with a real life Database where the ID-ParentID combination could be anything, since the user can move the entries around in the UI - per drag and drop in a tree. My problem was flatting it with the IComparer. I could have easily implemented a flat list with LINQ and stuff like you can find it here (my post) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968069 ,but this time I tried to get the same result with an IComparer.

Comment: @drankin2112 follow up since I ran out of characters: and my main problem with IComparer is how can I implement it with not a "complete" SortOrder but a repetitive SortOrder, that could have several SortOrder with a value 1, 2, 3 and so on but just under different parents, the answer that matches my goal the most is ruuds answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545137/#20801192 though I wouldnt write a method for the "HierarchicalSortOrder" but rather an property.

Comment: OK, new approach posted below. BTW, the reason that I'm trying so hard to help you is because I think you're question isn't getting the attention it should. Not really just for the bounty. Reading your other question gives me a better idea. I can see you wanting to drag-drop tree nodes all over the place inside a GUI. Let me know if it helps. I may just have to leave this one to the EF gurus :)

Comment: We have a hierarchical structure in an application using Entity Framework.  We did not use this approach as the hierarchy was too widely referenced.  You might want to consider beyond getting a tree control to display your hierarchy correctly.  Will you be doing joins against this structure with other entity framework entities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparer needs *lists* of SortOrders, following the entire ancestor chain for each record (parent, child, grandchild...). Like this:

```
ID --- Name --- SortOrder --- ParentID --- HierarchicalSortOrder
1  --- A    --- 0         --- null     --- 0
2  --- B    --- 1         --- 4        --- 0,1,1
3  --- C    --- 2         --- 1        --- 0,2
4  --- D    --- 1         --- 1        --- 0,1
5  --- E    --- 1         --- 3        --- 0,2,1
```

Then you can simply sort on HierarchicalSortOrder:

```
1 --- 0
4 --- 0,1
2 --- 0,1,1
3 --- 0,2
5 --- 0,2,1
```

The following function constructs this HierarchicalSortOrder:

```
public string GetHierarchicalSortOrder(HierarchyTable element)
{
   List<int> sortOrders = new List<int>() {element.SortOrder};

   while (element.Parent != null)
   {
      element = element.Parent;
      sortOrders.Insert(0, element);
   }
   return String.Join(",", sortOrders);
}
```

For simplicity, I assumed there are no ties in the sort order; if there are, you should also include element.ID in the list, otherwise children will become attached to the wrong parents.

Answer (score 1):

You should first flatten the structure with level numbers and then order by the levelNo+SeqNo

See the answer for my previous question:
[Flatten (with level numbers) a hierarchical list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641707/flatten-with-level-numbers-a-hierarchical-list)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extended version of your `HierarchyTable` class that gets you pretty close to what you're looking for. Basically it just adds the following.

- a `ToString() method`
- a static `HierarchicalSort()` method that sorts `ICollection<HierarchyTable>`.
- a static `GetNextNode()` method that that is used in the creating the HierarchicalSort.

The `HierarchicalSort` sort method creates both the hierarchy and the sort but only returns the sort. The hierarchy is just left behind so splitting it into two methods might be a good idea. When the function returns, the `topNode` variable contains the hierarchical data.

There was no real reason to use a custom IComparer because you're only really sorting on `SortOrder` in your example. You could easily extend it if you need to though.

```
public class HierarchyTable {
    public HierarchyTable(HierarchyTable parent) {
        Parent = parent;
        Children = new List<HierarchyTable>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties created by Entity Framework
    public virtual HierarchyTable Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HierarchyTable> Children { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("ID: " + ID).Append('\t');
        sb.Append("Name: " + Name).Append('\t');
        sb.Append("SortOrder: " + SortOrder).Append('\t');
        sb.Append("ParentID: " + ParentID);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Builds a hierarchical tree out of a List<HierarchyTable>
    // and copies each child row into a different 
    // List<HierarchyTable> as it is being built.
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public static List<HierarchyTable> HierarchicalSort(ICollection<HierarchyTable> inputlist) {

        HierarchyTable topNode = inputlist.ElementAt(0);
        HierarchyTable current = topNode;
        HierarchyTable child = null;

        inputlist.Remove(topNode);

        List<HierarchyTable> copyList = inputlist.Take(inputlist.Count).ToList();
        List<HierarchyTable> outputList = new List<HierarchyTable>() { topNode };

        foreach (HierarchyTable rec in inputlist) {
            do {                    
                child = GetNextNode(current, copyList);

                if (child != null) {
                    child.Parent = current;
                    current.Children.Add(child);
                    current = child;
                    copyList.Remove(child);
                    outputList.Add(child);
                }

            } while (child != null);

            current = topNode;
        }

        return outputList;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the first child of a sorted match on 
    // ID == ParentID. If you end up needing to sort on 
    // multiple columns or objects that don't already 
    // implement IComparer, then make your own comparer
    // class. The syntax would be:
    //
    // .OrderBy(x => x, new ComparerClass());
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    private static HierarchyTable GetNextNode(HierarchyTable current, ICollection<HierarchyTable> inputlist) {

        List<HierarchyTable> sublist = inputlist
            .Where(
                a => a.ParentID == current.ID
            ).OrderBy(
                x => x.SortOrder
            ).ToList();

        if(sublist.Count > 0)
            return sublist.First();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
    List<HierarchyTable> htable = new List<HierarchyTable>(){
        new HierarchyTable() {ID = 1, Name = "A", SortOrder = 0, ParentID = 0},
        new HierarchyTable() {ID = 2, Name = "B", SortOrder = 1, ParentID = 4},
        new HierarchyTable() {ID = 3, Name = "C", SortOrder = 2, ParentID = 1},
        new HierarchyTable() {ID = 4, Name = "D", SortOrder = 1, ParentID = 1},
        new HierarchyTable() {ID = 5, Name = "E", SortOrder = 1, ParentID = 3}
    };

    List<HierarchyTable> sorted = HierarchyTable.HierarchicalSort(htable);

    foreach (HierarchyTable ht in sorted)
        Console.WriteLine(ht);
```

Console:

---

```
ID: 1   Name: A SortOrder: 0    ParentID: 0
ID: 4   Name: D SortOrder: 1    ParentID: 1
ID: 2   Name: B SortOrder: 1    ParentID: 4
ID: 3   Name: C SortOrder: 2    ParentID: 1
ID: 5   Name: E SortOrder: 1    ParentID: 3
```

Good luck. I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Another approach would be to go ahead and flatten the hierarchy into a list and then call the sort method using an IComparer similar to this.

```
public class HierarchyTableComparer : IComparer<HierarchyTable> {
    public int Compare(HierarchyTable a, HierarchyTable b) {
        int comp = 0;

        if ((comp = a.SortOrder.CompareTo(b.SortOrder)) != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
        else if ((comp = a.ID.CompareTo(b.ParentID)) != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If the framework does the initial job of linking the hierarchical elements, then traditional sorting works because the list will already be sorted by levels.

Sample Usage :

```
//----------------------------------------------------
// Flattened Hierarchy
//----------------------------------------------------
List<HierarchyTable> htable = new List<HierarchyTable>(){
    new HierarchyTable() {ID = 1, Name = "A", SortOrder = 0, ParentID = 0},
    new HierarchyTable() {ID = 4, Name = "D", SortOrder = 1, ParentID = 1},
    new HierarchyTable() {ID = 2, Name = "B", SortOrder = 1, ParentID = 4},
    new HierarchyTable() {ID = 3, Name = "C", SortOrder = 2, ParentID = 1},
    new HierarchyTable() {ID = 5, Name = "E", SortOrder = 1, ParentID = 3}
};

htable.Sort(new HierarchyTableComparer());

foreach (HierarchyTable ht in htable)
    Console.WriteLine(ht);
```

Console:

---

```
ID: 1   Name: A SortOrder: 0    ParentID: 0
ID: 4   Name: D SortOrder: 1    ParentID: 1
ID: 2   Name: B SortOrder: 1    ParentID: 4
ID: 5   Name: E SortOrder: 1    ParentID: 3
ID: 3   Name: C SortOrder: 2    ParentID: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just using a recursive sort inside your HierarchyTable class. This is typically how I would navigate through an abstract syntax tree. If you plan on doing a variety of things with the HierarchyTable and you want minimal modifying of the class, then using the Visitor design pattern is probably your best choice. It is the de facto pattern to use when dealing with hierarchical node structures. Once implemented, it lets you add traversal-dependent functions to a tree node without changing the node's class at all.

I'd be happy to demonstrate how it's implemented if you haven't used it yet, just ask. I don't want to go too far down the wrong path for your question, again. :)

If you're interested, these wikis give a good overview of visitor pattern usage:

- [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)
- [Hierarchical Visitor Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HierarchicalVisitorPattern)

Essentially the standard pattern is best when you want to interrogate each node and the hierarchical pattern is best when you want to quickly short-circuit some of the nodes instead of wasting time. They both work on hierarchical data so I really don't like the naming distinction.

Anyhow, here is the recursive sort working from within the HierarchyTable class using an IComparer. Using these techniques also lets you start your sort from any level in a hierarchy.

```
    public List<HierarchyTable> FlatSort(IComparer<HierarchyTable> comparer) {
        List<HierarchyTable> sorted = new List<HierarchyTable>(){
            this   
        };

        if (Children.Count > 0) {
            //------------------------------------------------
            // Create sorted copy of children using IComparer
            //------------------------------------------------
            List<HierarchyTable> children = Children.ToList();
            children.Sort(comparer);

            foreach (HierarchyTable child in children)
                sorted.AddRange(child.FlatSort(comparer));
        }

        return sorted;
    }

    public class HierarchyTableComparer : IComparer<HierarchyTable> {
        public int Compare(HierarchyTable a, HierarchyTable b) {
            int comp = 0;

            if ((comp = a.SortOrder.CompareTo(b.SortOrder)) != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Sample Usage :**

```
    List<HierarchyTable> flatsort = hierarchyTableInstance.FlatSort(new HierarchyTableComparer());

    foreach (HierarchyTable item in flatsort)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```