# Flatten (with level numbers) a hierarchical list

Tags: c#, hierarchical-data

I have a collection of class X instances that point to themselves (self-referencing).

As an example, my class could look like this:

```
public class X {
   string Name {get;set;}
   List<X> Children {get;}
}
```

Now lets say I have a list of instances of class X, which can self-reference themselves N levels down.

My question is:  **How do get the instances of X from Nth level in my list?**

Basically I am trying to do in C# what a recursive self-referencing common table expression  would do in SQL, which is to flatten out a hierarchical list adding level numbers.

I have found this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118192/1171461
That works great but I still cant figure out how to get the elements ONLY from Nth level.

Comment: How would you identify the root?

Comment: @Vitaliy - Root would have level 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can modify the `Flatten` method in the linked example to include a level number as well, along these lines:

```
public class Leveled<T> 
{
    public T Item {get; set;}
    public int Level {get; set;}
}

public static IEnumerable<Leveled<T>> ToLeveled<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
                                            int level)
{
   return sequence.Select(item => new Leveled<T>{ Item = item, Level = level});
}

public static IEnumerable<Leveled<T>> FlattenLeveled<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
                                            Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childFetcher)
{
    var itemsToYield = new Queue<Leveled<T>>(sequence.ToLeveled(0));
    while (itemsToYield.Count > 0)
    {
        var leveledItem = itemsToYield.Dequeue();
        yield return leveledItem;

        var children = childFetcher(leveledItem.Item).ToLeveled(leveledItem.Level + 1);
        if (children != null)
        { 
            foreach (var child in children) 
               itemsToYield.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}
```

after this, you can just filter out the required level:

```
var thirdLevel = myCollection
           .FlattenLeveled(item => item.Children)
           .Where(leveledItem => leveledItem.Level == 2)
           .Select(leveledItem => leveledItem.Item)
```

Also, from @Servy's comment, since this is a breadth first approach (all of 1st level get done before any of the 2nd level is processed), we can use Skip/TakeWhile, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetHierarchyLevel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childFetcher, int level)
{
  return sequence.FlattenLeveled(childFetcher)
                 .SkipWhile(li => li.Level < level)
                 .TakeWhile(li => li.Level == level)
                 .Select(li => li.Item);
}
```

This will enumerate lazily, so any level further down the hierarchy will not be processed at all.

Comment: Note that in this case you're traversing the entire tree, but you could stop early, potentially.  If you use `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` instead of `Where` this wouldn't be hard to do.  Obviously this is reliant on the fact that you're doing a breath first traversal.  For a depth first traversal that's not an option.

Comment: @SWeko - I had to make a couple of changes before I could get it to compile. "yield return leveledItem.Item" should be "yield return leveledItem;" and "child.ToLeveled(leveledItem.Level+1)" should be "new Leveled<T>() { Item = child, Level = leveledItem.Level + 1 }"

Comment: @BlueChameleon The appropriate fix for the second problem is to move `ToLeveled` up to `children`, rather than on the singular `child`, instead of inlining the code from the helper method.  I'd also make the helper method private; there's no real need for an external user to use it.  I also prefer to call this method `Traverse`, as you're traversing a tree.

Comment: Sorry, my machine crashed right after posting the code, did not manage to test it and fix it (also the Skip/Take is a nice touch). Will edit it as soon as possible.

Comment: Edited the response, the code compiles and works. Added the Skip/TakeWhile improvement as well.