# Hierarchical data sorting C#

Tags: c#

I have a small hierarchy. Example:

entity:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

My hierarchy data look like:

```
Id = 1  Name = Item1    ParentId = NULL
Id = 2  Name = Item2    ParentId = 1
Id = 3  Name = Item3    ParentId = 2
Id = 4  Name = Item4    ParentId = 2
Id = 5  Name = Item5    ParentId = 3
```

The problem is I need to sort it that child nodes must be after its     immediate parent. The example bellow must look like

```
Id = 1  Name = Item1    ParentId = NULL
Id = 2  Name = Item2    ParentId = 1
Id = 3  Name = Item3    ParentId = 2
// the elements with parentID = 3
              Id = 5    Name = Item5    ParentId = 3
    //continue
    Id = 4  Name = Item4    ParentId = 2
```

Any adwices?

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your attempt.

Comment: Are you sure the example output is correct because the item with Id = 4 is not next to its parent (with id = 2) ?

Comment: You could put your data in a `DataTable` and sort that as done in the first part of this article: https://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/from-table-to-treeview-displaying-hierarchies

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968069/linq-sort-a-flat-list-based-on-childorder

Comment: I guess your class should be `Id` instead of `ID` and `int? ParentId` instead of `int ParentID`. Also check what Nasreddine commented.

Comment: You need to use a recursive method to sort.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Why is `Id=5` prior to `Id=4`? `Id=4` has `Parent=2`, so shouldn't that be **before** `Id=5`? I'm totally lost here.

Comment: I just realized this example is correct. Item1 has only one child, Item2. Item2 has two children, Item3 and Item4, but Item3 also has a child, Item5, so it must go immediately after Item3. Just like a directory structure. The indentation could be enhanced to make this more clear.

Comment: @user3609841, could you solve this? Have you seen all answers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `_list` of `MyClass` objects, then sort it first on `Name` field, then on `ParentId` field, like shown below using LINQ:

```
_list.OrderBy(L=>L.Name).ThenBy(L=>L.ParentId);
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Wouldn't that just sort by name and never by ParentId, because there no items with the same name?

Comment: Then you can probably just sort on Names. Best regards,

Comment: I didn't get you. Your code will list those items in the exact order they are shown in the question, ordered by name...

Comment: The question is confusing - read the comments thread above. Best regards,

Comment: Some people got confused by the order, but it's correct. Double check it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
I assume that 1st you want to order by parentid and in each parent you want to sort by id.

```
myClassList.OrderBy(parent=>parent.ParentId).ThenBy(parent=>parent.Id);
```

Comment: I thought about that, but that only works with two levels I think. Item with `Id = 5` won't appear right below its parent but at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass.data = new List<MyClass>() {
                new MyClass() { ID = 1,  Name = "Item1",    ParentID = null},
                new MyClass() { ID = 2,  Name = "Item2",    ParentID = 1 },
                new MyClass() { ID = 3,  Name = "Item3",    ParentID = 2 },
                new MyClass() { ID = 4,  Name = "Item4",    ParentID = 2 },
                new MyClass() { ID = 5,  Name = "Item5",    ParentID = 3 }
            };

            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.GetData(null, 0);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static List<MyClass> data = null;
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }

        public void GetData(int? id, int level)
        {
            List<MyClass> children = data.Where(x => x.ParentID == id).ToList();

            foreach (MyClass child in children)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" {0} ID : {1}, Name : {2}, Parent ID : {3}", new string(' ',4 * level),child.ID, child.Name, child.ParentID);
                GetData(child.ID, level + 1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a way to do it. As you can see, I overrode the `ToString` method and added a few more cases.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1} - {2}", Id, Name, ParentId);
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "Item1", ParentId = null });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 2, Name = "Item2", ParentId = 1 });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 3, Name = "Item3", ParentId = 2 });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 4, Name = "Item4", ParentId = 2 });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 5, Name = "Item5", ParentId = 3 });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 6, Name = "Item6", ParentId = 1 });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 7, Name = "Item7", ParentId = null });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 8, Name = "Item8", ParentId = 2 });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 9, Name = "Item9", ParentId = 6 });
        list.Add(new MyClass { Id = 10, Name = "Item10", ParentId = 7 });

        foreach(var item in list.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue).OrderBy(x => x.Id))
            ProcessItem(item, list, 0);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void ProcessItem(MyClass item, List<MyClass> list, int level)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", new string(' ', level * 2), item.ToString());
        foreach (var subitem in list.Where(x => x.ParentId == item.Id).OrderBy(x => x.Id))
            ProcessItem(subitem, list, level  + 1);
    }
}
```

Would something like this work for you?

If you need an actual ordered list, try this:

```
foreach (var item in OrderList(list))
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

(...)

private static List<MyClass> OrderList(List<MyClass> list)
{
    List<MyClass> orderedList = new List<MyClass>(list.Count());
    foreach (var item in list.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue).OrderBy(x => x.Id))
        AddItem(item, list, orderedList);

    return orderedList;
}

private static void AddItem(MyClass item, List<MyClass> list, List<MyClass> orderedList)
{
    orderedList.Add(item);
    foreach (var subitem in list.Where(x => x.ParentId == item.Id).OrderBy(x => x.Id))
        AddItem(subitem, list, orderedList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick (and show some better performance because we save the hierarchy in a lookup, instead of searching the IEnumerable on the fly):

```
public List<MyClass> SortHierarchically(IEnumerable<MyClass> myClasses)
{
    if(myClasses == null)
        return new List<MyClass>();

    var myClassesByParentId = myClasses.ToLookup(mc => mc.ParentId);
    var result = new List<MyClass>(myClasses.Count());

    int? currentParentId = null;
    MyClass currentItem = myClassesByParentId[currentParentId].Single();
    result.Add(currentItem);
    currentParentId = currentItem.Id;

    if(myClassesByParentId.Contains(currentParentId))
        result.AddRange(myClassesByParentId[currentParentId].SelectMany(mc => GetAllSortedChildren(mc, myClassesByParentId)));  

    return result;
}

public List<MyClass> GetAllSortedChildren(MyClass parent, ILookup<int?, MyClass> myClassesByParentId)
{
    var result = new List<MyClass>() { parent };
    if(myClassesByParentId.Contains(parent.Id))
        retsult.AddRange(myClassesByParentId[parent.Id].SelectMany(mc => GetAllSortedChildren(mc, myClassesByParentId)));

    return result;
}
```

It would be interesting to find a method of sorting this by standard LINQ, with some clever comparer or such.

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers above works well. This is a generic version.

```
public static class SortingMethods
{
    public static IList<T> OrderByHierarchical<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> items,
        Func<T, string> getId,
        Func<T, string> getParentId)
    {
        if (items == null)
            return new List<T>();

        var itemsByParentId = items.ToLookup(item => getParentId(item));
        var result = new List<T>(items.Count());

        var currentParentId = "";
        var currentItem = itemsByParentId[currentParentId].Single();
        result.Add(currentItem);
        currentParentId = getId(currentItem);

        if (itemsByParentId.Contains(currentParentId))
            result.AddRange(itemsByParentId[currentParentId].SelectMany(item => GetAllSortedChildren(item, itemsByParentId, getId)));

        return result;
    }

    private static IList<T> GetAllSortedChildren<T>(T parent, ILookup<string, T> itemsByParentId, Func<T, string> getId)
    {
        var result = new List<T>() { parent };

        if (itemsByParentId.Contains(getId(parent)))
        {
            result.AddRange(itemsByParentId[getId(parent)].SelectMany(item => GetAllSortedChildren(item, itemsByParentId, getId)));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```